# Preg_Replace for a big int fitting a certain pattern

Tags: php, regex, json

Within a GIGANTIC string I am trying to clean into json. I encounter something like this that breaks the script (usually multiple times from the same source)

```
{
 29646191: [bunchofjson]
}
```

is there a preg_replace I can do to replace all occurances of

```
{
 stringofrandomlysizednumbers: [anything]
}
```

With

```
{
 "string...numbers": [anything]
}
```

List of things that havent worked:

```
$output = preg_replace('/([^\\\])":([0-9]{10,})(,|})/', '$1":"$2"$3', $output);
$output = preg_replace('/("\w+"):(\d+)(.\d+)?/', '\\1:"\\2\\3"', $output);
$output = preg_replace('/("\w+"):(\d+)/', '\\1:"\\2"', $output);
$output = preg_replace('/(\d+):/', '"$1":', $output);
$output = preg_replace('/("\w+"):(\d+)(.\d+)?/', '\\1:"\\2\\3"', $output);
$output = preg_replace('/:\s*(\-?\d+(\.\d+)?([e|E][\-|\+]\d+)?)/', ': "$1"', $output);
$output = json_decode($output, true, 512, JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING));
```

(I json decode into an associative array when done in an ideal case)

Comment: Can you give some *actual* examples from your data?

Comment: Your original example seems like perfectly valid JSON. Maybe you should use better (or simply standard) JSON parser? What error message does it give you when it breaks?

Comment: Your fourth attempt in the "list of things that haven't worked" worked for me.

Comment: @mvp It looks like he's using `json_decode()`, it can't get any more standard than that.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing, and have not checked my code, but try this.

```
$output = preg_replace('/^\s*[0-9]{10,}.*/', '"string...numbers": \[anything\]', $output);
```

(I'm not sure the \[ and \] are required.  I don't think they are but I put them there just encase...
the preg_replace will replace any line that has any number of spaces, then 10 consecutive numberic characters.

Input is exactly like this?

```
{
 29646191: [bunchofjson]
}
```

Output will be like this

```
{
 "string...numbers": [anything]
}
```

Comment: I think you missed it, I needed more of
{
 "29646191": [bunchofjson]
}

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for this replacement:

```
$output = preg_replace('/(?<=\s)(\d+)(?=\s*:)/', '"$1"', $output);
```